# Semi-Transparent Textured Planes show Background Color through other planes

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, color

I have a large low poly model, being made for an N64 emulator, using N64 textures UV-mapped onto planes without (knowingly) using any materials.

[image]

As shown, my problem is that (using an example) the semi-transparent edges of a brown 'path' texture do not allow the 'grass' texture on the plane behind it to be seen through it, and instead show the background sky colour of Blender, seemingly culling the grass texture.

Confusingly, this only happens for some 'grass' planes, and others seem to render perfectly, leading me to believe that it is caused by the materials or other properties of the 'grass' planes, and not a fault of the transparent textures. When exported and used in emulators this isn't a problem, but in texture view with blender render it seems to occur randomly.

Thanks very much for any help.